# Not able to install ssh2 in centos 7

Tags: php, ssh, centos, centos7, ssh2

I am not able to install ssh2 in centos.

I using apache2 and PHP 7.3

I using below command and giving me error as below

```
yum install gcc php-devel libssh2 libssh2-devel php-pear make
pecl install -f ssh2
```

but it's showing me below error

```
No package php-devel available.
No package php-pear available.
```

please tell me what I missing.

Comment: yum install gcc php-devel libssh2 libssh2-devel php-pear make is this command executed successfully?

Answer (score 2):

In CentOS 7, what about enabling EPEL and then `yum install php-pecl-ssh2`

EDIT: Looks like CentOS 7 includes PHP 5 by default. The ssh2 page (https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) says:

> ssh2 1.0 and above is PHP 7 only. To install a version that is PHP 5
>   compatible you can run 'pecl install ssh2-0.13'

Comment: I using php 7.3